# snmp apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring, snmp

is there any snmp module to monitor apache 2.2?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any good SNMP modules to do this. However, you can do this yourself:

1. Using cron, dump [apachectl fullstatus](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/apachectl.html#options) to a file like /tmp/apache-status.txt. Do this once a minute or so. Or parse out the information you want, and dump it to this file.
2. Configure the snmp agent's exec feature to [run a command](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpd.conf.html) like `grep yourvaluehere /tmp/apache-status.txt`
3. Query that value using SNMP, as needed. Since /tmp/apache-status.txt is updated every minute or so, it is pretty up to date. The query will return the value of #2. You can do this for multiple queries/values.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use PRTG. 
[PRTG OFFICIAL WEB-PAGE](https://www.paessler.com/manuals/prtg/http_apache_modstatus_perfstats_sensor)

From my experience i can say that it's one of the best SNMP ever, with custom sensors. Until 100 sensors it's totally free.

Answer (score 0):

I never used it, but from google I found this [module](http://mod-apache-snmp.sourceforge.net/english/index.htm).

Comment: thanks, but this is only for apache 2.0.x :(

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read with attention.